# Block add to cart action and return to product page

Tags: event-observer, url, addtocart

I need ot check if the user can add the product to the cart and if not return to the product page with an error, I lsten to this event: `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add`.
And this is what I have written:

```
public function checkProductOnAdd(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    if(!self::isModuleEnabled()){
        return;
    }

    if($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == "checkout_cart_add"){

        $productId  = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product');
        $collection = Mage::getModel('country/product')->getCollection()
                                                       ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId);

        $country = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getRazorphynCountry;

        foreach($collection as $res){
            if(($res->allowed==0 && strpos($res->country, $country) !== false) || ($res->allowed==1 && strpos($res->country, $country) === false)){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('country')->__("Sorry, this product isn't available in your country"));
                //NOW?
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in my `config.xml`:

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
    <observers>
        <razorphyn_country_controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
            <class>Razorphyn_Country_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>checkProductOnAdd</method>
        </razorphyn_country_controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
    </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a new method in your controller that looks like this

```
protected function _isUrlInternal($url)
{
    if (strpos($url, 'http') !== false) {
        /**
         * Url must start from base secure or base unsecure url
         */
        if ((strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl()) === 0)
            || (strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, true)) === 0)
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

replace `NOW?` with

```
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$refererUrl = $request->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
if ($url = $request->getParam(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::PARAM_NAME_REFERER_URL)) {
    $refererUrl = $url;
}
if ($url = $request->getParam(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL)) {
    $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
}
if ($url = $request->getParam(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
    $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
}
$refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->escapeUrl($refererUrl);
if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($refererUrl)) {
    $refererUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
}
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
```

Comment: Thanks, the returning url is fine(check with log), however the product is added to the cart and magento redirect me to the shopping cart page(if I use `return`) or  a blank page if I use `die()`

Comment: See my edit. I forgot one line at the end `    Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();` You can add an `exit` or `die()` after that line.

Comment: Ok, I have added this: `Mage::app()->getRequest()->setParam('return_url',$refererUrl);` just before: `Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);` and now it looks like it works, let me know what you think

Comment: If it works for you then it the best solution :).